# How to write file in Data power local folder directory using java script?

Tags: javascript, ibm-datapower

anyone have any idea that how to write file in Data power local folder directory? I know we can write in temporary folder directory. It seems there is permission issue while writing the file in Data Power local folder director. I want to write in java script language. By using fs module, I can only create file in temp directory.

I tried creating a file in temporary directory using fs module. I couldn't be able to create a directory or access local directory in Data Power device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can actually, but it is a rather hacky solution.
You need to set up the SOMA endpoint and then you can use url-open to post the file to SOMA as a new config.

The performance is not good doing it that way, but I have written GWS to do it...

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't.

Slightly longer answer: By design, the local:/// filesystem on DataPower devices is read-only, meant to contain deployed code and config files.  This is explicitly stated in the docs for the GatewayScript fs module:

> You can read files from the local:, store:, and temporary: directories. You can write files in the temporary: directory.